# Updating table from form with user inputed date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a text box with a default value of today's date, that a user is also able to change if needed. The date is the date when an item is received and I need to update the purchase order table with this date. I have a button that commits these changes with a db.Execute, here's the code:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim w As String
Set db = CurrentDb
w = "UPDATE PO SET [Received] = " & Text20.Value & " WHERE [PONumber] = " & Text14.Value & " AND [LineItem] = " & Text18.Value & ";"
db.Execute w
db.Close
```

Text20 is the textbox with the default date. It has an input mask for shortdate on it. My problem is that when I click the button, it updates the [Received] field in the table, but not in the way I want it to. Instead of putting the date, it puts a time like 12:00:50 AM. I MsgBoxed the update statement and it looks fine to me so what is causing this problem? I've also tried using the CDate function but to no avail.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to format your date as a date. I would remove the input mask, they are a pain, and change your code to

```
w = "UPDATE PO SET [Received] = #" & Format(Me.Text20,"yyyy/mm/dd") & "# WHERE [PONumber] = " & Me.Text14 & " AND [LineItem] = " & Me.Text18 & ";"
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks! can I ask why it was showing a time instead of a date?

Comment: Dates are stored as DateTimes and are actually decimal numbers , the integer part is the day number, the fractional part the time component. 
If you evaluate 7/6/2018 as a a calculation you get a very small number, which as a date would equate to 31/12/1899 and a time in Access or something similar. Have a read https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=date-time-data-type-vba-access 
for a good explanation

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
If IsDate(Text20.Value) Then
    w = "UPDATE PO SET [Received] = #" & Format(Text20.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# WHERE [PONumber] = " & Text14.Value & " AND [LineItem] = " & Text18.Value & ";"
Else
    ' Something
End If
```